# WildCards in SSIS Collection {not include} name xlsx

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I have a process built in SSIS that loops through Excel files and Import data only from those that include name *Report*.

My UserVariable used as Expression is:  `*Report*.xlsx`
and it works perfectly fine. Now I am trying to build similar loop but only for files that DOES NOT include *Report* in file name.

Something like `*<>Report*.xlsx`

Is it possible?

Thanks for help!

Matt

Comment: Duplicate question. This works. Just tried it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093008/ssis-exclude-certain-files-in-foreach-loop-container

Comment: @manderson this is not a duplicate. It is some kind of workaround

Comment: I said duplicate, because the answer is the same. I didn't want to basically copy that answer into this question, but since it's not a duplicate... I put the answer in for the user.

Comment: The OP was asking if he can achieve this using Expressions. My remark was on the word `duplicate` not the whole comment. The link you provided is helpful for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this using SSIS expression (*something like `*[^...]*.xlsx`*) you have to search for some workarounds:

**Workarounds**

**First**

*Get List of - filtered - files using an `Execute Script Task` before entering Loop and loop over then using ForEach Loop container (Ado enumerator)*

1. You have to a a SSIS variable *(ex: `User::FilesList`)* with type `System.Object` *(Scope: Package)*
2. Add an `Execute Script Task` befor the for each Loop container and add `User::FilesList` as a **ReadWrite Variable**
3. In the Script Write The following Code:

   Imports System.Linq
       Imports System.IO
       Imports System.Collections.Generic

   ```
   Public Sub Main()
       Dim lstFiles As New List(Of String)
       lstFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp", "*.xlsx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("Report")).ToList)

       Dts.Variables.Item("FilesList").Value = lstFiles

       Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
   End Sub
   ```
4. In the For each Loop Container Choose the Enumertaion Type as 'From variable Enumerator' and choose `FilesList` variable as a source

*ScreenShots*

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Second**

*Inside the for each loop add an `Expression Task` to check if the file contains `Report` string or not*

1. Add a variable of type `System.Boolean` *(Name: ExcludeFile)*
2. Inside the ForEach Loop Container add an `Expression Task` component before the DataFlowTask you that imports the Excel File

[image]

3. Inside The Expression Task write the following:

   ```
    @[User::ExcludeFile]  = (FINDSTRING(@[User::XlsxFile], "Report", 1 ) == 0)
   ```

[image]

4. Double Click on the connector between the expression task and the DataFlowTask and write the following expression

   ```
   @[User::ExcludeFile] == False
   ```

[image]

*Note: It is not necessary to use an `Expression Task` to validate this you can use a **Dummy DataFlowTask** or a **Script Task** to check if the filename contains the Keyword you want to exclude or not*

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, put a Script task before your first task. Connect those two with a line. Right click that line and set Constraint Options to expression. Your expression would look like this...

```
FINDSTRING(@var, "Report", 1) == 0
```

Where @var is the loop iterable.

Only files without "Report" inside will proceed to the next step.

Referencing this exact answer. [SSIS Exclude certain files in Foreach Loop Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093008/ssis-exclude-certain-files-in-foreach-loop-container)