# Use SSIS Foreach loop to loop multiple folders

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, foreach-loop-container

I have one main folder, which contains 40+ folders. I have created an SSIS package that creates subfolders in 22 of the 40 folders. I want to use a Foreach Loop in my package to loop through only the 22 folders for my script to return the names and date/timestamp of new subfolders created.

I can currently loop through all 40 folders, but I have not been able to locate information on how to target specific folders.

Any suggestions on references are appreciated.

Comment: Why not generate a list of the paths you need using an initial C# script and store the results in a local dataset for the loop to iterate over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of specific folder using a Script Task, or you can use the for each loop with an expression task to achieve this, just follow my answers on:

- [WildCards in SSIS Collection {not include} name xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628842/wildcards-in-ssis-collection-not-include-name-xlsx/42635146#42635146)
- [Exclude specific Sub Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283195/exclude-specific-sub-folders/44974176#44974176)

*Script Example:*

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim lstFiles As New Generic.List(Of String)

    'Assuming that C:\Temp is the main folder
    'And We want to include all subdirectories that contains "Report" word

    For Each strDirectory As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Temp", "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

        If Not strDirectory.Contains("Report") Then Continue For

        lstFiles.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

Next


    Dts.Variables.Item("FilesList").Value = lstFiles

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: Any similar reference on Including specific Sub Folders?

Comment: @DavidF what method you want? script task or expression task?

Comment: @DavidF in the first link, in the script task method, i used Linq to filter files from the List. Just replace the conditions. It is the same way. Just read the answers and you will get it

Comment: @DavidF or in the script task you can loop over the list item using `For each strpath as String in lstFiles` and delete unwanted pathes

Comment: I was looking for Script tasks.

Comment: @DavidF the first link provided contains exactly what you are looking for, i will copy the script and make some editing

Comment: @DavidF i added an example take a look. This will get all files from specific folder, and loop over them in the ForEach loop container

Comment: No this is not converted well to c#

Comment: Hadi, 

I have tried to modify your script example, but it continues to error.

I cannot import System.Linq System.IO or System.Collections.Generic. However, I did add them as using.

A couple of issues are with IO.Directory and SearchOption. They do not appear to be recognized.

Would you please take a look at the modified code I embedded, and let me know your expert opinion as to why it may be erroring.

I will provide the code in the following post.

Much appreciated for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Public Sub Main()
{
 lstFiles As New List =("t:\customers\subsystem");

  IO.Directory.GetDirectories("T:\customers     \subsystem","*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

  strDirectory.Contains("New Orders");
  lstFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("T:\customers    \subsystem, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

  Dts.Variables.Item("FilesList").Value = lstFiles;
  Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success;

End Sub
}

Comment: @DavidF my script is a vb.net script not c#. Just add a new script task. And select its language as visual basic not c# from its properties

Comment: I understand. Let me try again.

Comment: Hadi, I am down to 2 errors, which not being familiar with VB, I don't know how to resolve. 

1. strDirectory gives me options in a dropdown. Change to Directory, Change to IO.Directory, Change to System.IO.Directory. There are also selections for creating a method, property or field stub.

2. lstFiles has a dropdown for creating a method, property or field stub.

I added System.Linq, System.IO, and System.Collections.Generic to the Imports region.

Any assistance on which selections I should select are appreciated.

Comment: Give me a moment and i will give u a reply

Comment: Hadi, The update resolved. I guess the next question is what is next? I have checked the Exclude specific Sub Folders and WildCards in SSIS Collection {not include} name xlsx posts that you referenced. 

One reference using an expression task with a data flow task inside the Foreach Loop, while the other references a data flow task inside the loop. Which example should I follow?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: @DavidF i am sorry. You should use the second approach `only data flow task inside the loop`

Comment: That got it. Much appreciated.