# SQL SSIS - Moving certain number of files

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am looking for a way to move files from one folder to another using SSIS.

I have a foreach loop with an empty data flow and a file system task in the foreach loop.

I want to specify a certain number of files to be moved using a variable. Increments of 1000 files at a time.

Please Help

Comment: Do you just want to move the files without importing them or anything?  Or do you want to import them to the DB then move them?

Comment: The first step to doing this is to open SQL Server Data Tools and try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to **move files from directories to another** one using variables all you need is a `Execute File System Task` inside a `Foreach Loop container` of type `file enumerator`. There are many articles found on the internet that describe the whole process step-by-step.

- [For Each Loop with File System Task](http://msbi2012.blogspot.com/2013/04/for-each-loop-with-file-system-task.html)
- [Move Multiple files using File System Task in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/move-multiple-files-using-file-system-task-in-ssis/)

If want to **exclude some directories or files** then you should use a Script Task or an Expression Task to apply filter, you can check my answers on:

- [Exclude specific Sub Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283195/exclude-specific-sub-folders/44974176#44974176)
- [WildCards in SSIS Collection {not include} name xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628842/wildcards-in-ssis-collection-not-include-name-xlsx/42635146#42635146)