# $xlnm excel sheets

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have bunch of sheets in excel file. when I am looping the sheets its picking `$xlnm #_filterdatabase` as excel source.

How can I ignore loading `$xlnm #_filterdatabase` sheets?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot ignore these sheets, since they exists but they are hidden. Temporary sheets names always endswith an underscore, you can use a similar logic to filter them (using Expression Task or Script task) :

```
if (!strSheetname.EndsWith("_") & & !strSheetname.EndsWith("_filterdatabase") && strSheetname.EndsWith("$")){}
```

Note that a valid sheet name must ends with a dollar sign $

If you decide to use an Expression task you must use Findstring() function.

You can check the following answer, to learn how to implement a filter inside a foreach loop container:

- [WildCards in SSIS Collection {not include} name xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628842/wildcards-in-ssis-collection-not-include-name-xlsx/42635146#42635146)